# Grease Pencil Line Art Modifier Anti-Aliasing Causing Weird Effects

Tags: grease-pencil, antialiasing

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzTN2yTgTj0) tutorial trying to dip my feet into grease pencil, but whenever I apply the Line Art modifier, and the Anti-Aliasing Threshold in the render settings is anything more than 0, I get this really weird look. It happens for both the automatically created lines from the modifier, and the manually drawn lines on the model.

It looks better at 0, but still has a lot of noticeable aliasing. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is a known issue, I can't seem to find anything. I've tried a higher resolution render, and it didn't help the line art lines at all.

This is using the Eevee engine. The only potential issue is I am running on Linux with an AMD card, but that doesn't seem to affect any other aspect.

Threshold at 0:
[image]

Threshold at literally anything else:
[image]